# Poetry with local repo and no PyPI?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I like Poetry for keeping track of which dependencies are mine, and which ones are transitive. At the same time, I'm thinking of speeding up my deployments (which are thousands of times a day, as we build small tools that are deployed to virtual machines, do their thing and then the whole VM is incinerated) by keeping my dependencies as downloaded wheels inside my repos. With `pip` I can use `--no-index --find-links ./wheels`, with `poetry` I've read about configuring private repos, but it seems they only support `http(s)://` urls, not `file://` urls.

Is there a way I can tell `poetry` to look for wheels in a local folder and never PyPI?

Comment: What about not using Poetry at all for the deployment on the VMs? Install everything from wheels even your own project. Use `poetry build` to get a wheel of the project and copy it to the VMs along the wheels of all dependencies. Then use `pip` to install all wheels.

Comment: @sinoroc Turns out, it doesn't allow to do that. What can be done is build a wheel (dependencies not included), but then export all the dependency wheels along with ours into some kind of an artefact repository

Answer (score 1):

Recently I meet the same issue, and find a solution for this problem.

1. With the help of [pypiserver](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/), you can run a local server for pipy server.
2. After that you can download the required packages by `pip download <your_package>` on the computer with internet connection, and then copy the downloaded packages to the computer unaccessible to internet.
3. Then you register a private reporitory for your poetry project like `poetry source add --default local http://localhost:8080/simple/`.
4. In your poetry project directory, run `poetry add --source local <your_packags>` to add the required package to your poetry peoject as usual.

For more information of how to use pypiserver, you can check the [doc of pypiserver](https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver/blob/master/README.rst).

By the way, you may run across a problem related to *“Retrieved digest for package not in poetry.lock metadata”*. You can run pypiserver by `pypi-server run <PACKAGES_DIRECTORY> --hash-algo sha256` to solve it. Visit [here](https://py4u.org/questions/71558637/) for more information.